# google chrome- how to change the user agent

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I want to change user agent in chrom without the need to install a new plugin or any [3rd party code](https://superuser.com/questions/334241/user-agent-switcher-for-chrome). I could find only changing it for one time in the debug mode, how can I hack it and make it to change for good.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://osxdaily.com/2013/01/16/change-user-agent-chrome-safari-firefox/)?

Comment: I tend to load up Polipo and set everything to use it as a proxy and turn off all my browsers' caching. This way you have 1. a centralized cache for all your HTTP stuff 2. Really good implementation of HTTP pipelining and a weird protocol 'abuse' PMM 3. Change user-agents/other headers easily for everything